# Why do my earbuds keep changing the volume up and down whenever I move the wire?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, headphones

I've already tested my earbuds out on my computer and my guitar amp by moving around and constants flapping the wires and pushing them, so the problem is isolated to my iPhone only (I have the iPhone SE). It's weird because the sound almost cuts out for a second, then the volume turns down to a very quiet setting, and after a second or so the volume will turn back up to what it was originally.

Notes:

- I'm not using Apple earbuds.
- I have an iPhone SE.

Comment: Likely a bad connection on your iPhone. I'd clean out the headphone jack & see if the problem still exists.

Comment: As Scott said above - it could be a dust clogged headphone jack. It may also be something to do with the earphones themselves especially if they're not Apple ones. Are they in good condition and from a reputable brand? Do they have a remote built in for changing volume?

Comment: I had the same problem when using a specific pair of bluetooth headphones.  It ended-up being a bad headphone play/pause switch (caused by sweat or water in the switch).  I'd [clean the headphone jack](https://www.gazelle.com/how-to/iphone/how-to-clean-an-iphones-headphone-jack) & if that doesn't help, the headphone jack could be bad.

Comment: My guess is you activate Siri very briefly by accidentially causing the same clicking sounds that the switches on the Apple headsets do when pressed.

Comment: I have as similar problem with Mpow headset over Android. When sound start, it starts at a very low level then raises. If no more sound it goes down again. This makes no problem with music or phone calls but it is very disturbing when using Duolingo (the sound is intermittent when pressing buttons, listening new exercise...). I think it may be related with power saving but no idea how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you are in a noisy environment, using your earphones, as you say, plugged into your phone.

This happened to my while riding my motorbike with earphones on. The built-in microphone is being hit by a lot of noise, and then the signal is sent and your phone OS tries to protect you by lowering the volume.

Try the same earphones with some tape on the microphone (a tiny hole somewhere on the earphones), or try them in any situation without a lot of outside noise.

If they work ok, your problem is what I'm telling you about.

There is a few choices you can take to fix your problem. I'll state them so the first options are the cheapest or more reasonable ones.

**1.** Search for a setting on you IOS, or an app to make volume not depend on outside noise. There is some apps that lock the volume level I think.

**2** Put some tape or whatever you consider to make your microphone deaf.

**3** Change earphones to ones without built-in mic.